# How to connect macbook 11.4 big sur remotely with windows server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, macos-big-sur

I have `3 RDP's (2 of Windows server 2012 R2 and 1 Windows Server 2008 R2)`. By using Microsft Remote Desktop, I am able to get connected remotely with the two Windows Server 2012 R2. But I am unable to connect with Windows Server 2008 R2. I am getting the below error.

[image]

Previously I was able to connect with all three. Also, I want to mention that in the windows environment I am not facing any issue with the RDP.

I am stuck to it and don't know what to do. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/187583/rdp-works-pc-to-pc-but-i-get-error-code-0x204-mac.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and this is what I did to get working back the RDP client on a Macbook pro mid-2015 with the last big sure release.

First make sure that :

1. the remote server `IS` online
2. the remote server `IS` accepting RDP connections
3. the remote server firewall `IS` configured correctly with the right port
4. the remote server `IS NOT` configured to accept **only connections with NLA**

After validating the above points, then on your client (the Mac) you can try to get working the RDP with this first step :

- `remove` (**please make a backup**) the file `UBF8T346G9.com.microsoft.rdc` located in `/Users/[Your username]/Library/Group Containers/` then `reboot` your Mac.

If it still doesn't work, you could try to remove the app, reboot, then re-install the app again.
You can also analyze the Event-Viewer on the 2008 R8 server to see if there is something to help you to spot the issue.

More information about troubleshooting RDP :

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/troubleshoot-remote-desktop-disconnected-errors

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem some years ago.

here's the solution:

- Read the article carefully. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/troubleshoot-remote-desktop-disconnected-errors.
- And check if the remote server IS accepting RDP connections.
- And also check if the remote server accepting only connections with NLA.
- delete the file UBF8T346G9.com.microsoft.rdc and Reboot.

And if still doesn't work, then totally uninstall / remove the app and install again and check.

Thank You

Comment: I am able to connect with RDP via windows environment but not with MAC